# How to use python's "ord" function in Tensorflow without py_func

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my program I need to obtain the base 10 value of a char as per the ASCII table, which I would normally get in python with `x = ord('a')` for example.

I have a string placeholder which I'm mapping to get every single character and from that I need to get back the equivalent base 10 number.

Given that I need to save and restore my model I cannot use the `py_func` to achieve this and I can't find an alternative solution.r

Comment: What do you mean by "base 10 value of a char"? The base 10 value of `'a'` doesn't exist, because there is no such digit as `a` in base 10. Do you need to get the ASCII value, then format that as a base-10 numeral, like the string `'65'` for `'a'`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant the base 10 numeric version of the ASCII value, like 65 in the case of 'a'.

Comment: The integer `65` doesn’t have a base, it’s just a number. The string `’65'` is the base-10 representation of that number. I still don’t understand which of those two you want.

Comment: Well, yes it does, otherwise it would be `41` in base 16 and so on, but this is not the point of my question. I don't mind it being an integer or a string, all I need is something that looks like a `65` for `'A'`, `66` for `'B'` and so on.

Comment: But it _is_ `'41'` in base 16 and so on. Anyway, if you want the number, the function is just `ord`; if you want the base-10 string, the simplest is probably `lambda x: str(ord(x))`.

Comment: I am looking for something like the function `ord` but that can be used when given as input a Tensorflow's tensor, i.e. `ascii_value = ord(my_tensor)` where `my_tensor` is the tensor which will contain a single character when run in a session. I think you missed the fact that I'm talking about Tensorflow in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tf.decode_raw](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_raw):

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=())
number = tf.decode_raw(a, out_type=tf.uint8)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(number, feed_dict={a: 'AB'}))  # prints [65 66]
```